# Store entity with entity reference field programmatically?

Tags: 8, entities

I want to create an ECK by hard coding, The ECK being created, but the entity references that I assigning to the main entity cause the problem.

I have two entity references

- field_student_account that I assign the Student Account by id 10
- field_students that I assign the Students by id 48,
- field_enrollment that I assign the Enrollment by id 270,

> Error: Call to a member function label() on null in Drupal\eck\Controller\EckEntityListBuilder->buildRow() (line 43 of modules\contrib\eck\src\Controller\EckEntityListBuilder.php).

I tried these codes:

```
  // Define entity type and bundle.
  $entity_type = "attendees";
  $bundle = "attendees";

  // Get definition of target entity type.
  $entity_definition = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getDefinition($entity_type);
  // Load up an array for creation.

  $entity_data = [
    'title' => 'this is test new',
    'field_student_account' => 10,
    'field_students' => 48,
    'field_enrollment' => 270,
    'field_status' => 'Active',
    $entity_definition->getKeys()['bundle'] => $bundle,
  ];
  $new_entity = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage($entity_type)->create($entity_data);
  $new_entity->save();
```

here are the values for created entity from the front end.

```
#values: array:12 [▼
    "id" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "15"
    ]
    "type" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "attendance"
    ]
    "uuid" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "9a1fd3ec-3d7d-4926-a1d2-fcafc8fce3c2"
    ]
    "langcode" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "en"
    ]
    "title" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "group lesson"
    ]
    "created" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "1561802666"
    ]
    "changed" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "1561802705"
    ]
    "default_langcode" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "1"
    ]
    "field_enrollment" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "target_id" => "271"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "field_status" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "value" => "Inactive"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "field_students" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "target_id" => "69"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "field_student_account" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "target_id" => "27"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

And this is the data that stored when I try it pro-grammatically

```
EckEntity {#1106 ▼
  #values: array:8 [▼
    "id" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "16"
    ]
    "type" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "attendees"
    ]
    "uuid" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "1048d24d-ffc7-4243-81c1-b26b5e9e9ecb"
    ]
    "langcode" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "en"
    ]
    "title" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "this is test new"
    ]
    "created" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "1561806843"
    ]
    "changed" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "1561806843"
    ]
    "default_langcode" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "1"
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this for entity reference fields:
Single value:

```
$entity_data = [
'field_student_account' => ['target_id' => 10],
];
```

Multiple values:

```
$entity_data = [
'field_student_account' => [
    ['target_id' => 10],
    ['target_id' => 11],
  ],
];
```

Hope that works :)

Comment: As I test it in new test case it working fine with Entity Reference but I not working on my real case.

Comment: Finally, I found my crazy mistake that makes the system unusable.
here you can see that I insert in **attendees** bundle  but the correct one is **attendance**

Mine >`"x-default" => "attendees"`

System >`"x-default" => "attendance"`